# Quadrant Scatter chart with kendo ui

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I wanna draw a scatter kendo chart with four area(Quadrant).
**How i can draw custom lines across `xAxis` and `YAxix`?**
and **How i can paint each area different?**
(i'm using MVC wrapper but any help is useful)

```html
<div class="demo-section k-content wide" dir="ltr">
    @(Html.Kendo().Chart(Model)
                    .Name("chart")
                    .Title("chart")
                    .Legend(legend => legend
                        .Visible(false)
                    )
                    .Series(series =>
                    {
                        series.Scatter(model => model.QuestionsAVG, model => model.Weight);
                    })
                    .XAxis(x => x
                        .Numeric()
                        .Title(title => title.Text("Average"))
                    .Labels(labels => labels.Format("{0}")).Min(0).Max(10)
            //.PlotBands(bands =>
            //{
            //    bands.Add().From(5).To(10).Color("#c00").Opacity(0.1);
            //})

            .YAxis(y => y
                .Numeric()
                .Title(title => title.Text("Weight"))
            
             .PlotBands(bands =>
             {
                 bands.Add().From(5).To(10).Color("#c00").Opacity(0.1);
             })
            .Labels(labels => labels.Format("{0}")).Max(10)
            )
            
        .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
            .Visible(true)
        .Template("#=  dataItem.Question  #")
        )
    )
</div>
```

I want somthing like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFyTW.png).

Comment: You could do something with PlotBands: http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/UFElE

Comment: Thank you . It was vary useful .